# Why does Rails console say "cannot load such file -- readline"?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-console

I am new to Ruby on Rails, and am using RVM to manage Ruby versions.

My laptop has Ruby1.8.7 installed, but my project is using RVM, Ruby1.9.3 and Rails 3.2.11.

I can't run `rails c` or `rails console` without it giving me the following error:

```
/home/phil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/completion.rb:9:in `require': cannot load such file -- readline (LoadError)
from /home/phil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/completion.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/phil/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:3:in `require'
from /home/phil/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/phil/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:38:in `require'
from /home/phil/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:38:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Which `rails` command are you running? What's the output of `which rails`?

Comment: Thanks Stuart for reply. I answered below.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to have the readline libraries installed when you compile Ruby.

If you are on CentOS/Redhat/Fedora Linux, install the package using:

```
sudo yum install readline-devel
```

Or, on Ubuntu, use:

```
sudo apt-get install libreadline6 libreadline6-dev
```

and then recompile Ruby.

Comment: Thanks for responding Stuart and John. I run "rvm use 1.9.3" it displays back "ruby 1.9.3p392 (2013-02-22 revision 39386) [i686-linux]". Everything works fine, it's only when I run "rails c" or "rails console" I get the above error. I ran "sudo apt-get install libreadline6 libreadline6-dev" and installed them, but I still get the error unfortunately.

Comment: johnkoht - when you say "then recompile ruby", what exactly do you mean?

Comment: Then recompile ruby with "rvm uninstall [RUBYVERSION] followed by rvm install [RUBYVERSION]". That's working now, thanks a million johnkoht, legend!

Comment: Glad you got it working (sorry I didn't see your other messages until now).